# I lost my iPad, can I track it if the battery is dead?

Tags: ipad

If the battery is dead, how can I track my iPad? What if it says iCloud offline on device? Is it because my iPad is wiped or the power is dead?
- if so, how can I figure out the seriel number on my iPad to track it in that sort of way

Answer (score 2):

You can only track it when it is online and connected to the internet.  If it's not online, it could be turned off, the battery could be flat, it could just be out of WIFI range, etc - could be anything.  Use iCloud.com and Find my iPhone to set it to alert when it comes online is all you can really do.

Your best hope is that you were using IOS7 on the device, and had it logged into iCloud, because that way no-one else can use it, even if they wipe the device, without they re-enter your own Apple ID iCloud login.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not turned on/online you can not track it.

Depending how experienced the "lucky finder" is, it might be wiped already.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it just if it's online and connected to the internet. If the iPad runs iOS 7, the man who found it have to know your Apple ID and the password of your account, and to enter any password he have to be connect to the internet, so if the iPad runs iOS 7 you still have hope.